# Переключение внешнего вида каталога товаров 1с битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

Я использую на странице компонент catalog.section. Как лучше реализовать переключение между шаблонами в компоненте? Если допустим мне нужно из списка переключится на плитку. В этом же компоненте есть шаблон и со списком и плиткой, например под названием list и board.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если используется комплексный компонент `catalog`, то нужно править в файле `section.php` перед вызовом комплексного компонента, если используется компонент `catalog.section` именно просто на странице, то добавляете код именно на страницу перед вызовом компонента.

Механизм состоит в том, что перед вызовом компонента добавляем ссылки, по нажатию на которую мы попадаем на ту же страницу, но с добавленными параметрами, например `site.ru/catalog/?view_mode=list`.

При загрузке страницы, скрипт считывает эти параметры (и можно сразу удалить из URI для красоты ссылки), но главное прочитать выбранное значение:

```php
$request = \Bitrix\Main\Application::getInstance()->getContext()->getRequest();
$viewMode = trim($request->get('view_mode'));
```

Далее, сверяем, есть ли у нас такое значение среди возможного выбора (от дурака). Записываем в выбранный параметр в сессию (чтобы при перезагрузке выбралось запомненное и не пришлось снова переключаться). Например так:

```php
if(strlen($viewMode) || (array_key_exists("view_mode", $_SESSION)) || $arParams["DEFAULT_LIST_TEMPLATE"])
{
    if(array_key_exists($viewMode, $arViewMode)) {
        $_SESSION['view_mode'] = $viewMode;
    }
    elseif(array_key_exists(trim($_SESSION['view_mode']), $arViewMode))
    {
        $viewMode = trim($_SESSION['view_mode']);
    }
    else
    {
        $viewMode = $arViewMode[0];
    }
}
else
{
    $viewMode = 'table';
}
```

Ну а далее просто пихаем `$viewMode` как название шаблона для компонента `catalog.section` и естественно такие шаблоны нужно сделать.

p.s. Не забудьте отметить вопрос решенным, если ответ подошел. Спасибо.